# Thunderbird Contacts sync with Ubuntu One on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu-one

How can I get Thunderbird Contacts to sync with Ubuntu One on Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. It appears evolution-couchdb (and thus the Thunderbird extension which depended upon it) has been removed; likely due to API changes in upstream evolution-data-server, and no resources to update the plug-ins.

It's also worth noting that it was [announced](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-November/003474.html) in November 2011 that desktopcouch/couchdb support would gradually removed from Ubuntu One. However, replacement infrastructure is being worked on in the form of [u1db](https://launchpad.net/u1db) to replace the pieces which couchdb was being used for.